# MVC 5 - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a project in MVC 5. I'm using .NET 4.6 and VS2015. This morning, I've tried to install some packages. This is my packages.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net46" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProjectDb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Project-20150626153959;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Project-20150626153959.mdf"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer><runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="B77A5C561934E089" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I've looked for answers on the Internet, but none of them worked. Thanks for help!

Comment: I had something similar to this for me the other day, but for the Google.Apis library.  I removed the offending nuget packages, removed any ` <dependentAssembly>` tags from every app.config/web.config in my solution and then installed the package again and all was well again.

Comment: If you can paste the full error message, that will contain the version number of the assembly that the solution is looking for.  This will be useful, because you'll need to also check that the assembly being search for is the correct version as the one in the Nuget packages.config for the solution and all projects in your solution.